# Mostrar dados da tabela que estarão activos brevemente com atributo 'disabled' e também os que já estão activos?

Tags: php, html

Tenho este código abaixo e a funcionar, ele publica os dados apenas quando se indica 1 no campo 'Pronta' da tabela, e se estiver o número 0 os dados não são mostrados. Mas eu queria que quando os dados da tabela que estão marcados com 0, e que são palavras representadas por butons, neste caso indicando portanto que não estão publicados, fossem publicados com o atributo disabled, para mostrar ao utilizador os temas ou palavras que brevemente vão estar activos. Alguém tem uma ideia sobre esta programação?

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = $_GET["letter"];

$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from dicionario_basico  where Pronta != 0 AND palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY palavra";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_basico   where pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc";

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Experimente assim que funciona: Você pode pegar todos os items ...**

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';

$letter = $_GET["letter"];

$sql = "SELECT id,palavra,pronta from dicionario_basico where palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY palavra";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(`palavra`, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_basico where pronta != 0 ORDER BY abc";

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

?>
```

na tabela no html insere uma classe se o resultado tiver 0 ou 1 prontas, tipo assim:

```
<th scope="row" id="" style="background-color:#fafafa;"><?php 
                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      if($row["pronta"] == 1){
                   ?>
```

então no css do button das palavras activas, ou marcadas com 1, poderá estilizar assim ...

```
<button style="margin-top:-2px;font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; border:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><? echo $row["palavra"]; ?></button></a><br/>
            <?
          }else{?>
```

e no no css das palavras inactivas e marcadas com 0 poderá estilizar as tr com a classe disabled. Estas palavras ficam à vista mas sem o link activo para que os utilizadores fiquem apenas a conhecer as palavras que brevemente vão estar activas).

```
<button style="margin-left:-16px;margin-top:-2px;font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; border:none;-moz-outline-style:none;" type="button" aria-disabled="true" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg disabled" ><? echo $row["palavra"]; ?></button><br/>
          <? }
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar todos os items

```php
$sql = "SELECT id,palavra from dicionario_basico where palavra LIKE '".$letter."%' ORDER BY palavra";

$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(palavra, 1, 1)) As abc from dicionario_basico ORDER BY abc";
```

então na sua tabela no html você insere uma classe css se o resultado tiver 0 pontas, tipo assim:

```php
<table>
    <?php foreach($results as $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo ($value['pontas'] == 0 ? 'disabled' : '')?>">
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

então no css você poderá estilar todas as tr com a classe *disabled*

```css
tr.disabled {
   color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Neste momento está assim e eu ainda não consigui associar ou trocar pelo seu código:   <tbody>
<!-- LISTA DAS PALAVRAS -->
                <tr>
                <th scope="row" id="" style="background-color:#fafafa;"><?php 
                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                   ?>

Comment: A solução está em ``` <?php echo ($value['pontas'] == 0 ? 'disabled' : '')?>```. meu código é só um exemplo.